# Задачка по C++. Помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: c++

Ввести целочисленный массив, состоящий из 17 элементов. Заменить элементы кратные трем на сумму нечетных по значению элементов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int str = 16; 
int matr[str];  
int summ = 0;       
   
for (int n = 0; n < str; n++)

{
    matr[n] = n++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    if (matr[i] % 2 != 1)
    {
        summ = summ + matr[i];
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < str; ++i)
{
    if (matr[i] % 3 == 1)
    {
        matr[i] = summ;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < str; ++i)
{
    std::cout << matr[i] << " ";
}
```

}

Код мне выводит немного не понятные значения

Comment: *Ввести целочисленный массив* Я чёта ввода в упор не наблюдаю...

Comment: Чтобы вывести что-нибудь понятное, надо сперва ввести что-нибудь понятное. А вы этого не сделали. Массив не заполнен значениями.

Comment: Конечно заполнен. Смотрите первый цикл. В нем, кстати, и ошибка - вы инициализируете элементы значением выражения `n++`, и эта же переменная используется в качестве индекса элемента - у Вас банальный выход за границы массива.

Comment: @isnullxbh Выхода за пределы массива здесь нет.

Comment: @DmitryK, да, спасибо. Я ошибся, они просто не все инициализируются.

Comment: В ответах уже указали на ошибку. От себя добавлю, что кратность подразумевает деление без остатка на число, а вы в строчке `matr[i] % 3 == 1` ищете числа, остаток от деления которых равен 1, т.е. не кратные 3

Comment: Переформулируйте Ваш вопрос. Сейчас у Вас говорится про "немного непонятные значения", нужно конкретизировать, в чем их "непонятность". Мне кажется, вопрос пытаются закрыть только из-за этого, других причин я не вижу - код есть, что-то делали; то, что опущен ввод, даже проще (в данном случае) для того, чтобы воспроизвести проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Вы заполняете не весь массив. В цикл в операции присвоения нельзя делать инкремент, поскольку он изменяет индекс и получается, что вы заполняете значения через 1.

```
for(int n = 0; n < str; n++)
//    matr[n] = n++;  // неправильно
    matr[n] = n+1;  // правильно
```

Ну и по условию задачи массив должен быть из `17` элементов. Значит должно быть `const int str = 17;`

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрим ваше заполнение массива:

```
for (int n = 0; n < str; n++)
{
    matr[n] = n++;
}
```

Пройдем руками пару итераций... Итак, n = 0, далее `matr[0] = 0`, потом `n` увеличивается в теле цикла, потом - в заголовке... На следующую итерацию `n==2`, и мы заполняем `matr[2]`. `matr[1]` остался с мусором внутри...

Как исправить, догадываетесь?

Лично я бы записал вместо

```
for (int n = 0; n < str; n++)
{
    matr[n] = n++;
}
```

вот это:

```
for (int n = 0; n < str; matr[n] = n++);
```